# C# I'm not sure what to do next to pull the information from both comboboxes

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I'm not sure where to go next for this project. The **calculate** button should use the conversion calculations, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it, and I can't find any relevant answers since its pulling the data from two combo boxes.
Also, the combo-boxes should change based on what the user picks. So, for example, if the user chooses "in" from the first combo-box, they should not be able to choose "in" from the second combo-box.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very appreciative.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const double mi_To_km = 1.6093;
    const double Km_To_mi = 0.6214;
    const double ft_To_m = 0.3048;
    const double m_To_ft = 3.2808;
    const double in_To_cm = 2.54;
    const double cm_To_in = 0.3937;
    const double ft_To_mi = 1 / mi_To_ft;
    const double mi_To_ft = 5280;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cboFrom.Items.Clear(); //clear the combobox

        string[,] measurements =  
        {  {"in"}, {"ft"}, {"mi"}, {"cm"}, {"m"}, {"km"} };


        foreach (string str in measurements)
        {
            cboFrom.Items.Add(str);
        }

        foreach (string str in measurements)
        {
            cboTo.Items.Add(str);
        }

    }

    public bool IsDecimal(TextBox txtEntry, string entry)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtEntry.Text);
            return true;
        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(entry + " must be a decimal value.", "Entry Error");
            txtEntry.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int from = cboFrom.SelectedIndex;
        int to = cboTo.SelectedIndex;


    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
        cboFrom.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cboTo.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: take a break. re-think. what shall happen? if both values are the same, is that really a problem? why not let the user pick and correct the choices at will back and forth? now look at the selectionchanged event! here you can test the choices and then react: send a warning, enable or disable a button or simply let it go: going from ft->ft is not the end of the world..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to modify your code:

```
    string[] measurements = { "in", "ft", "mi", "cm", "m", "km" };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string str in measurements)
        {
            cboFrom.Items.Add(str);
        }

        foreach (string str in measurements)
        {
            cboTo.Items.Add(str);
        }
    }

    private void cboFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboTo.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            cboTo.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string str in measurements)
            {
                cboTo.Items.Add(str);
            }

            cboTo.Items.RemoveAt(cboFrom.SelectedIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cboFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == cboTo.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                cboTo.Items.Clear();

                foreach (string str in measurements)
                {
                    cboTo.Items.Add(str);
                }

                cboTo.Items.RemoveAt(cboFrom.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void cboTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboFrom.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            cboFrom.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string str in measurements)
            {
                cboFrom.Items.Add(str);
            }

            cboFrom.Items.RemoveAt(cboTo.SelectedIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cboTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == cboFrom.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                cboFrom.Items.Clear();

                foreach (string str in measurements)
                {
                    cboFrom.Items.Add(str);
                }

                cboFrom.Items.RemoveAt(cboTo.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what would be the best approach to adding the code for the btnCalculate_click?

Comment: So, everything works now, except I am still having problems with removing items from the comboboxes.

Comment: Can you give details how are you removing items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectedIndexChanged event like this:

```
    private void cboFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCalculate.Enabled = true;

        if (cboTo.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (cboFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == cboTo.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                btnCalculate.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void cboTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCalculate.Enabled = true;

        if (cboFrom.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (cboFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == cboTo.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                btnCalculate.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you go about removing "in" from the "To" combobox if "in" was selected from the "from" combobox?

Answer (score 0):

I would add this code:

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int from = GetIndex(cboFrom.SelectedItem.ToString());
        int to = GetIndex(cboTo.SelectedItem.ToString());


    }

    private int GetIndex(string _measure)
    {
        int _index = -1;

        switch (_measure)
        {
            case "in":
                _index = 0;
                break;
            case "ft":
                _index = 1;
                break;
            case "mi":
                _index = 2;
                break;
            case "cm":
                _index = 3;
                break;
            case "m":
                _index = 4;
                break;
            case "km":
                _index = 5;
                break;
        }

        return _index;
    }
```